# Aurelia: fetch-client response doesn't have my data

Tags: aurelia, fetch-api

I've been banging my head against fetch-client for too long and I need some help.

I'm getting some data from Skyscanner. The request hits their API and Chrome's dev tools list it in the network tab as a complete fetch request with code 200 and the correct response body.

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
@inject(HttpClient)
export class Flights {
    constructor(http){
        http.configure(config => {
          config
            .withBaseUrl('http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/')
            .withDefaults({
                mode: 'no-cors',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-type' : 'application/json'
                }
            });
        });

        this.data = "";
        this.http = http;
    }
  activate() {
    this.http.fetch('browsequotes/v1.0/GB/GBP/en-GB/UK/anywhere/anytime/anytime?apiKey=MYAPIKEYGOESHERE')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.response);
                console.log(response.content);
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(ex => {
                console.log(ex);
            }); 
  }
}
```

But when the response object is printed it has NOTHING in it:

```
Response {}
  body: null
  bodyUsed: false
  headers: Headers
  __proto__: Headers
  ok: false
  status: 0
  statusText: ""
  type: "opaque"
  url: ""
  __proto__: Response
```

All of the remaining console.log's produce *undefined*

Am I using fetch-client incorrectly? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice you're receiving an [opaque response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type) (`type: "opaque"`). Opaque responses does not allow you to read them. This is due to the `no-cors` mode you set before. You should use the `cors` mode and SkyScanner should provide the proper headers for your API key which is something I think [they don't do](http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/FAQ#qf23).

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense. Also it's good to know that's what opaque means. Thank you for that. I'd read the note on their API, but they made it seem like it was only for their Live Pricing service. Must be for their whole API then. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue except its not opaque and the Body is a ReadableStream. But when I try to get the data out using .then(data => ) it is undefined. I traced the call in Chrome and can see the call is successful and I can see the JSON coming back.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue which can fall under same heading so leaving an answer here as I couldn't find anything on the net. May be I'm just stupid but i was doing this before...

```
.then(response => {response.json()})
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Banged my head against this for a day and turned out the fix is:

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Or

```
.then(response => { return response.json()})
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Simple really and nothing to do with Aurelia or Fetch but understanding of Javascript syntax.